# unable to login to sqlplus in oracle

Tags: database, oracle, oracle10g

Yesterday I have installed oracle database 10g XE and after installation I have created my own password and after that whenever I try to use sqlplus and then it asks for the username password.
SO for that I type username - system and password -(what I created)
but after that I am not able to login.
By the way I am able to use it in browser but I am not able to use it in sqlplus.
Help me please with it.
Here is the screenshot of the problem.
[image: this is the login problem that I am getting]

Plus I am also having one more problem and that is I am not able to use **scott schema** .
Help me for that so that I can use that.

Comment: At least on the screenshot, you actually typed **systme**... To be on the safe side, you could type **sqlplus username/password** (with the actual values) to rule out typos... What exactly do you mean by "I am not able to use scott schema"?

Comment: oh sorry for the wrong typing
but the problem is still there and also I ahve tried but after it I am getting error.
username password not found

Comment: yeah that is working in browser (chrome and mozilla both)
but it is not working in sqlplus.
There is one more problem - I think sqlplus is not working properly.

Comment: Let me tell you all the things.
At the time of installation I have created password for sys and system.
Through that i am able to login using my browser.
But when I use same info in sqlplus then it shows me error message.

And for the Scott/tiger it is saying that I am interring wrong username password.
Now same software my friend is using in windows 7 and he is using it fine, but I am windows 8 user and I am not able to use it.
Please help me with it.

Comment: When you spell system correctly and supply the right password, do you still get ORA-01017, or something else? Can you log in with scott/tiger in your browser (I assume the XE home page on port 8080)?

Comment: yes Alex that is XE home page is on port 8080 ans scott tiger does not work here.

Comment: Do you possibly have (remains of) more than one installation on your machine?

Answer (score 2):

1. `sqlplus /nolog`
2. `select username, account_status from dba_user;`

after hitting enter... it will show the list of the databases... then at the last
you'll find a `username` as `SYSTEM` with the `account_status` as `OPEN`

so

1. sqlplus
2. enter username: SYSTEM

   enter password: *the one you specified at the time of installation*

Comment: Can you try to format this a little better so it's easier to read? Make use of the "code" tags when possible.

Comment: These commands are for Command Prompt.. that explains it all i guess

Answer (score 0):

1. you have to check your spelling in username/password.
2. password is case sensetive, if you entered Initial letter you should use Initial lettaers, same thing for uppers, and lowers letters in password.
3. are you able to login to scott in browser? if there is no scott schema you have to [install scott schema from sample schemas](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63457/installing-scott-schema-for-oracle-11g-express/63520#63520) first.

Comment: yeah it looks like there is no scott schema in my oracle 10g
but same setup is installed by my friend and he is having that how ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try step by step:

1. run `CMD`
2. typing `sqlplus`
3. user-name: `sys/password@dbname as sysdba`

```
Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
SQL>
```

**Reference:**  https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/12c/r1/Windows_DB_Install_OBE/Installing_Oracle_Db12c_Windows.html
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/datamine.112/e16807/security.htm#DMADM013

Answer (score -1):

I had that same issue. Does your password contain a `@` character? Mine did. After I changed the password (without `@`), it worked.